# (Automated Action) Odoo Problem with write() and do for loop

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I'm trying to update the 'sequence' value in model 'product.supplierinfo' with an Automated Action, so that when the supplier's price are updated from a purchase order, that supplier is prioritized to calculate the replenishment cost. To achieve that, the new/updated record must get the lowest 'sequence' value for that product.

[Automated Action Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wx28o.png)

Automated Action Settings:
Model: product.supplierinfo
Action: Execute Python code
Condition: Create and update

This part of the py resets the sequences starting from 2 successfully:

```
val = 1
registers = model.search([('product_tmpl_id','=',record.product_tmpl_id.id)], order = "sequence asc")
for reg in registers:
  val = val + 1
  reg['sequence'] = val
```

And this other one gives the updated/new line the sequence value 1 successfully:

```
record.write({'sequence': 1})
```

However, when put all together, all the lines get sequence 1:

```
val = 1
registers = model.search([('product_tmpl_id','=',record.product_tmpl_id.id)], order = "sequence asc")
for reg in registers:
  val = val + 1
  reg['sequence'] = val
record.write({'sequence': 1})
```

As I'm pretty noob, I even assumed that maybe the loop wouldn't end with the indent and tried this other one to proof I'm missing something (first setting sequence 1 to the aimed record and then dropping that record from the search method). It still gets 1 on all the register's sequence value:

```
record.write({'sequence': 1})
val = 1
registers = model.search([('product_tmpl_id','=',record.product_tmpl_id.id),('id','!=', record.id)], order = "sequence asc")
for reg in registers:
  val = val + 1
  reg['sequence'] = val
```

Any idea why it doesn't set the trigger record's sequence 1 and then the rest from 2 and on?

Comment: Hi, what is the domain for the records on the autom. action? Seems to me, that your `sequence` write calls are triggering more autom. action calls by itself?

Comment: Automated Action Settings: Model: product.supplierinfo Action: Execute Python code Condition: Create and update

Comment: I checked and there are no other Automated Actions nor Server ones on the module product.supplierinfo. Also checked if any other action would mention that model in their pyhon code. Nothing. Thanks

Comment: No i meant that your action is triggering itself, because you update `product.supplierinfo` records in it, so it should trigger for them the same action, which sets their sequence to 1 too. I'm not fully sure why everything isn't ending in an infinite loop, because there is no ending condition.

Comment: Oh! Makes sense. I'm not quite sure how to solve it. It is running with an empty domain, and I don't see how it could be solved form over there. On the other hand, a line like  `if env.user.id != 1:` wouldn't work as triggers run with the user.id of the user that trigger them originaly, right?

Comment: Maybe it's possible to use the context like calling `reg.with_context(skip_sequence_recomputation=1).sequence = new_sequence` and using this at the beginning of the code to let odoo do nothing if in context.

Comment: I couldn't make the skip_sequence_recomputation code work. I also tried disabling the Automated Action at the beginning of the code and then enabling it at the end (prohibitions would pop up). Finally, checking the last update datetime vs current time did the trick to prevent the loop´. Thanks a lot, I wouldn't have thought about the loop promlem on my own. @CZoellner wanna post the working code as an answer so I can vote it and this question gets closed?

Comment: can't you post it yourself? Because it is your work after all ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @CZoellner we found that my code was creating a loop running through all the records, when editing the sequence value it would trigger the Automated Action again. For some reason it wouldn't throw an error of infinite loop.

However, the solution that did the trick was checking the maximum `write.date` of the group of records to verify if the Automated action had already gone through it.

The final working code is:

```
val = 1
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S'
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S")
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(now, fmt)

registers = env['product.supplierinfo'].search([('product_tmpl_id','=',record.product_tmpl_id.id),('id','!=', record.id)], order = "sequence asc")
maxi = max(reg.write_date for reg in registers)

d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(maxi, fmt) 
diff = (d2-d1).seconds

if diff > 1:
  for reg in registers:
    val = val + 1
    reg['sequence'] = val
  record.write({'sequence': 1})
```

Thanks to @CZoellner for collaborating